# Error while accessing oneDrive: User's mysite not found

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to access oneDrive via Graph api, and when I hit the api, I get `User's mysite not found.`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "User's mysite not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "13eb583d-c29a-42af-8868-bae06d554538",
      "date": "2018-05-18T06:06:55"
    }
  }
}
```

So, looking out for the solution, I saw an [issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/292) where they said to get OneDrive for Business' location, But this returns `UnauthorizedAccessException`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?select=mySite

{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message":
      "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3489894e-faa0-42c6-9f3b-e76c4708ce15",
      "date": "2018-05-18T06:10:00"
    }
  }
}
```

And when I hit for `/me` endpoint, there I see an empty array for `provisionedPlans`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "id": "7e8397a6-b299-34a2-af06-d3487t5b5174",
  //...
  "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
  "provisionedPlans": []
}
```

My access token is

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEWDhHQ2k2SnM2U0s4MlRzRDJQYjdySGc5dDJ4SmxkODFMRURNY1FuN3pMYVgyektLaDR2SF9FSFltd1JaQ3Y5TU55VDJOR250VmlDQVFmTXpiTWxoYkZWQ19nSEdtaWhfWlJfcVlpaGRyMHlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiaUJqTDFSY3F6aGl5NGZweEl4ZFpxb2hNMllrIiwia2lkIjoiaUJqTDFSY3F6aGl5NGZweEl4ZFpxb2hNMllrIn0.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2dyYXBoLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvM2FjMThiOGMtNjY4ZC00NzBhLWJhMDctYWU0MjdlMTkwZGEyLyIsImlhdCI6MTUyNzE0MDg2MCwibmJmIjoxNTI3MTQwODYwLCJleHAiOjE1MjcxNDQ3NjAsImFjciI6IjEiLCJhaW8iOiJBVFFBeS84SEFBQUE4UitBY2U4bnpGU0JXRGg4NUFHUWE1VXowT05yZEZ5VzhXQnYvZ1BnVE1nMWx4MnNibkZSbUdrbHVsNVhiME5SIiwiYWx0c2VjaWQiOiI1OjoxMDAzMDAwMDk3NURDNEFCIiwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdLCJhcHBfZGlzcGxheW5hbWUiOiJJbnRlbGlOb3Rpb24gRGVtbyIsImFwcGlkIjoiYWU0OTY3MGItNmIwYi00NjgxLWE5OTAtNmZmZWQ1NTFiMjMwIiwiYXBwaWRhY3IiOiIxIiwiZW1haWwiOiJrb21hbC5oZW5kcmVAcmF5a29yLmNvbSIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiSGVuZHJlIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6IktvbWFsIiwiaWRwIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvMWJiYTE1NTktM2RjYS00NzBjLWE2YjUtMDViNzlmOGZjYzlmLyIsImlwYWRkciI6IjE4Mi43Mi4xMjMuMTUwIiwibmFtZSI6IktvbWFsIEhlbmRyZSIsIm9pZCI6IjdlODM5N2E0LWIxOTktNDRhMi1hZjA0LWI4NDg3YzViNTQ3NCIsInBsYXRmIjoiMTQiLCJwdWlkIjoiMTAwM0JGRkRBQUNDRjg4NiIsInNjcCI6IkFsbFNpdGVzLk1hbmFnZSBEaXJlY3RvcnkuUmVhZC5BbGwgRmlsZXMuUmVhZFdyaXRlIEZpbGVzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwgR3JvdXAuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCBJZGVudGl0eVByb3ZpZGVyLlJlYWQuQWxsIE15RmlsZXMuV3JpdGUgcHJvZmlsZSBVc2VyLlJlYWQiLCJzdWIiOiJxQWVpeEFCNGFidHpKS05FQ0hSSFlRU3RFOURKTkRSS080aU9CcmN1cFZvIiwidGlkIjoiM2FjMThiOGMtNjY4ZC00NzBhLWJhMDctYWU0MjdlMTkwZGEyIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJrb21hbC5oZW5kcmVAcmF5a29yLmNvbSIsInV0aSI6IkxtTnJoX1FZbUVHbUtSY1JHcWtGQUEiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAifQ.JtXMDO2Whs24ItQIIPBEZj93Go5z0QowyZCy-msAw7-heGu7yQZrppuvBfv-rrAS1bvFw_aBDBALzX7rlHwsiU9KaEzrRdzUgc9lciDhuGsPZddGEZrSpTuhBPvLa-xI8_1bLMhSChLECU63rMnBYHZJesenWqPL0w1DsmkUHeR01Ff7l8pgsH3jemRK2NAr4LD-wyQrumJxz2h45luO9dICqPOGjI9hwrjNpSDJnhienDkUsrcOA2ijnWglCJ3GRN9RfrJ93osCaO3WpUoTIy66NApYR__YDGzO4HsTk_MA9OSQCHcw5mOaOeRKZmRTDPIokyYpeNgXBK9FmZivBg
```

Can't figure out that it is a access problem or provisioning problem. Can anyone suggest what's going wrong here.

Comment: I also tried to manually provision the onedrive via [this](http://www.thinkscape.com/Provision-OneDrive-For-Business-Personal-Sites/) but still get empty provisionedPlans array.

Comment: Can you open OneDrive directly from the web UI? It doesn't sound like you have a OneDrive licensed/provisioned.

Comment: we have Office 365 Business Premium subscription. and I'm using onedrive from last 4-5 months from web UI.

Comment: What scopes have you requested and which grant flow are you using to obtain your token?

Comment: The scope provided is `AllSites.Manage Directory.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All IdentityProvider.Read.All MyFiles.Write profile User.Read` and grant type is `authorization_code`.

Comment: Your scopes look okay. Can you add an example of the token you're receiving back to your question?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I added the access token in the question.

Comment: This looks okay but there are a couple of invalid scopes. It might be worth removing them just to eliminate them as a problem: `AllSites.Manage` and `MyFiles.Write` are not valid Graph scopes. Also, you're requesting `profile` but not the required `openid` scope to go with it. I would remove `profile` as well.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Okay! Well I added those scopes just because of the error `user Mysite not found`. Well I started looking at the problem from another angle, actually I've two account with different domains like one is `jack@abc.com` and other is `john@xyz.com` but both are been added in one AD, where I'm able to access graph API with jack's account but not able to access by john's account. Is there anything suspicious you feel?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur any updates on that?

Comment: That is a little odd. The `userPrincipalName` should be their alias/mailnickname + the default domain. How were these users created?